# Extracting rows from attribute table and save as new shapefile using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I have a shapefile made up of polylines. Polylines have a contour attribute. I want create new shapefiles based on these contour attributes. Something like this:

```
depth = [-10, -20, -30, -40]
map = myfile.shp
for d in depth:
    for row in map:
        if row.contour == d
            add to newshape_d.shp
```

Sorry if this code makes no sense, but that is the gist of what I am trying to do.

Comment: Use [Split By Attributes](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/split-by-attributes.htm)

Comment: @BERA unfortunately this will split by every type of contour depth and I only want to select a few.

Comment: Field calculate first and divide them into depth groups, or select by attribute

Comment: If you stay with ArcPy rather than using Split By Attributes then you should look into using a SearchCursor to read features from the first shapefile and then an InsertCursor to write them to the second shapefile.

Comment: @PolyGeo thanks, I will try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very straightforward approach would be to select the features that match the values in `depth` and write them to a the new shapefile

```
import arcpy

depth = [-10, -20, -30, -40]

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(map, 'subset', 'contour IN {}'.format(depth)) #the SQL syntax may need tweaking
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management('subset', 'newshape_d.shp')
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with PolyGeo, SearchCursor and InsertCursor are the fastest ways to go here.

I usually first create a search cursor to iterate through the entire source feature to populate a dictionary or list of what I want to add to the new shapefiles.

Then I will iterate through that dict or list and use an insert cursor to add the records to each file I want respectively.  Usually iterating though dictionaries and lists are much much faster than dealing with shapefiles and tools.  There is a bit of overhead in creating the dict but your still money ahead and this way you only have to create 1 Search Cursor and as many InsertCursors as you have contour intervals.

Some relevant docs for you

- **SearchCursor**: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/searchcursor.htm
- **InsertCursor**: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/insertcursor.htm
- **CreateFeatureClass**: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/create-feature-class.htm

Here is an example script.

```
import arcpy
import os

workspace_path = r"C:\pathtoworkspace"
PolylineShapefile = r"C:\PathToFile"

tf = r"C:\PathToFile"  # path to a template shapefile if you want, makes it easier to set up fields you want.
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(1000) # spatial reference


ContourList = [10, 20, 30, 40]
contour_dict = {}

# iterate through current file and grab contours you are interested in
for contour in ContourList:
    # Note you can specify the fields the SearchCursor will access, for performance they used to recommend
    # Spelling out which fields you wanted but in the docs now.
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(PolylineShapefile) as cursor:  #Search cursor
        for row in cursor:  # IterateThrough rows
            if row[1] == contour:  # if which ever field contour is in matches
                # beautiful function that will create a new list or append to existing in dict
                contour_dict.setdefault(contour, []).append(row)

# iterate through the dict to add to new shapefile.
# keys should be your contor interval and the value is a list of records from original table.
for contour, rows in contour_dict.items():
    # Process Filename and create new shp.
    target_filename = "{contour}ContourExport.shp".format(contour)
    arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(workspace_path, target_filename, "POLYLINE", template=tf, spatial_reference=sr)
    # Create a search Cursor to add in new selected records
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(os.path.join(workspace_path,target_filename)) as cursor:
        # iterate through the records for the specified contour and add to newly created shapefile
        for row in rows():
            cursor.insertRow(row)
```